# How to scroll to next dynamic instance (wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm building a wp theme that calls all posts to the home page.

Each instance is full screen and has a button nested inside that instance labelled 'next'. When the user clicks that button, I want the interface to scroll to the next dynamically loaded instance, but anything I come up with doesn't seem to work.

Any jQuery gurus out there care to explain how this might be accomplished?

As always any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out a while back on my own, so I'll answer my own question in case anyone else is wondering.

Seems the magic is done with the jQuery [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) & [.next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) selectors. I also added a [.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to the `.click` function as it prevents the anchor from going through the href (default) function.

Here's the markup:

```
<article id="article1" class="home-article">
    <a href="#" class="home-article-next">next</a>
</article>

<article id="article2" class="home-article">
    <a href="#" class="home-article-next">next</a>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.home-article {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('.home-article-next').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var article = $(this).closest(".home-article").next()
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: article.offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```